# R: Join/merge list of data frames by common columns and appending

Tags: r, list, join, merge, dataframe

I am looking for a way to merge a (long) list of data frames into a data frame, by keeping common columns and appending a column that contains values different in each data frame.

```
head(dflist[['sampleA']])
seqnames   start     end width strand           gene reads
1     chr1   30366   30503   138      + hsa-mir-1302-2     7
2     chr1 1102484 1102578    95      +   hsa-mir-200b  2158
3     chr1 1103243 1103332    90      +   hsa-mir-200a 12939
4     chr1 1104385 1104467    83      +    hsa-mir-429  2775
5     chr1 3044539 3044599    61      +   hsa-mir-4251     0
6     chr1 3477259 3477354    96      -   hsa-mir-551a   464

head(dflist[['sampleB']])
  seqnames   start     end width strand           gene reads
1     chr1   30366   30503   138      + hsa-mir-1302-2     6
2     chr1 1102484 1102578    95      +   hsa-mir-200b  1407
3     chr1 1103243 1103332    90      +   hsa-mir-200a  8874
4     chr1 1104385 1104467    83      +    hsa-mir-429  1721
5     chr1 3044539 3044599    61      +   hsa-mir-4251     0
6     chr1 3477259 3477354    96      -   hsa-mir-551a   349
```

what I look for is an output like that:

```
 seqnames   start     end width strand           gene reads.sampleA
1     chr1   30366   30503   138      + hsa-mir-1302-2     7
2     chr1 1102484 1102578    95      +   hsa-mir-200b  2158
3     chr1 1103243 1103332    90      +   hsa-mir-200a 12939
4     chr1 1104385 1104467    83      +    hsa-mir-429  2775
5     chr1 3044539 3044599    61      +   hsa-mir-4251     0
6     chr1 3477259 3477354    96      -   hsa-mir-551a   464
reads.sampleB
1                                      6
2                                   1407
3                                   8874
4                                   1721
5                                      0
6                                    349
```

I'm pretty sure this is a rather simple and common task, but I can't find/google a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could try `join_all` for a long list of data.frames

```
  library(plyr)
  join_all(dfList, by=names(dfList[[1]][-7]))
  #   seqnames   start     end width strand           gene reads reads
  #1     chr1   30366   30503   138      + hsa-mir-1302-2     7     6
  #2     chr1 1102484 1102578    95      +   hsa-mir-200b  2158  1407
  #3     chr1 1103243 1103332    90      +   hsa-mir-200a 12939  8874
  #4     chr1 1104385 1104467    83      +    hsa-mir-429  2775  1721
  #5     chr1 3044539 3044599    61      +   hsa-mir-4251     0     0
  #6     chr1 3477259 3477354    96      -   hsa-mir-551a   464   349
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple merge. By default the merge function merges on all common names but you want to merge on all but the last name, so remove it from the character vector supplied to `by`:

```
merge(dflist[[1]], dflist[[2]], by=names(dflist[[1]][-7])  )
  seqnames   start     end width strand           gene reads.x reads.y
1     chr1 1102484 1102578    95      +   hsa-mir-200b    2158    1407
2     chr1 1103243 1103332    90      +   hsa-mir-200a   12939    8874
3     chr1 1104385 1104467    83      +    hsa-mir-429    2775    1721
4     chr1   30366   30503   138      + hsa-mir-1302-2       7       6
5     chr1 3044539 3044599    61      +   hsa-mir-4251       0       0
6     chr1 3477259 3477354    96      -   hsa-mir-551a     464     349
```

Comment: In order to use this, I would need make a function and call it via Reduce, as far as I understand. I prefer the solution via plyr because it is much easier for me to understand what it does (I dont entirely understand what Reduce does), that's why I selected the other answer as solution. Thanks anyway!